# Both cores run constantly at 100%

Tags: windows-7, linux, cpu

I run a dualboot Fedora/Windows 7 computer. It will work fine for the first ten minutes or so after booting, after which it is rendered completely useless and slow. CoreTemp gives that both cores (Intel Core 2 Duo T7300) run almost constantly at 100%. Thinking back, this problem never really occured until I started dualbooting. Could there possibly be a connection? I don't really need Windows 7 anymore, and am more than open to deleting it, but I find this problem, while incredibly annoying, somewhat interesting. They are note particularly warm (around 50 celcius)

Comment: Try to update your BIOS ....

Comment: Does this happen on fedora too? What are the apps that take the most cpu? you can check that through the Task Manager on windows.

Comment: What programs did you install after you began dualbooting? I suspect one of those is eating your CPU time.

Comment: Yes, this happens on Fedora too. It does not matter what apps I am running; even if I close everything, including explorer.exe, the cores will go haywire after a certain amount of time.

Comment: So it happens with both windows and fedora after setting up dual-boot or just fedora?

Comment: It happens always. I just did a clean install of Fedora, the problem is still present.

Comment: Could you share your computer specs? In the absence of a clear process that's consuming resources, maybe there is an ingrained functionality in both OSes (probably disk-related) that may take most out of the CPU. Also, how did you perform the dualboot process (it probably isn't related, but one never knows).

Comment: At this point, the dualboot process is not relevant anymore: I did a clean install of only Fedora. Picture includes specs. http://imgur.com/UwWfRdN

Comment: @AndrewThompson is your promblem solved or not?  cores run constantly at 100%?